# Kubernetes pods cannot communicate internally

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, kubernetes, kubernetes-service

In my K8 cluster, I have two Deployments in the same namespace. One Deployment is for Database-Postgres and the other Deployment is for Tomcat. The Tomcat should be accessible from outside hence I have configured "NodePort" Service and for internal communication I have created a "ClusterIP" Service by exposing the port of Postgres (i.e. 5432). Once everything is deployed, I want the Tomcat pod to communicate with the Postgres pod. But when I "curl postgres-service:5432" from Tomcat pod, I get "Connection refused" message. Is there any misconfiguration?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tomcat-service
  namespace: application
  labels:
    app: application-tomcat
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: tomcat-port
    targetPort: 80
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: application-tomcat

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
  namespace: application
  labels:
    app: application-postgres
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    name: postgres-port
  selector:
    app: application-postgres

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: application-tomcat-deployment
  namespace: application
  labels:
    app: application-tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: application-tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: application-tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: application-container
        image: tomcat
        command:
          - sleep
          - "infinity"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
     
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: application
  name: application-postgres-deployment
  labels:
    app: application-postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: application-postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: application-postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres
        command:
          - sleep
          - "infinity"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: postgredb
```

Postgres pod is listening on port '5432' and database is running.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Resources in the Namespace

```
$ kubectl get all -n application
NAME                                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/application-postgres-deployment-694869cd5d-wrhzr   1/1     Running   0          9m9s
pod/application-tomcat-deployment-6db75ffb6d-ds8fr     1/1     Running   0          9m9s

NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/postgres-service   ClusterIP   10.32.0.207   <none>        5432/TCP       9m9s
service/tomcat-service     NodePort    10.32.0.59    <none>        80:31216/TCP   9m9s

NAME                                              READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/application-postgres-deployment   1/1     1            1           9m9s
deployment.apps/application-tomcat-deployment     1/1     1            1           9m9s

NAME                                                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/application-postgres-deployment-694869cd5d   1         1         1       9m9s
replicaset.apps/application-tomcat-deployment-6db75ffb6d     1         1         1       9m9s
```

Comment: You don't need to create the `Service` of type `ClusterIP` manually/explicitly. The `NodePort` service internally creates a `ClusterIP` service which can be used for internal communication.

Comment: I omitted Service of  type ClusterIP, but then it will create only a NodePort service. So then how can I specify the hostname in Tomcat in order to communicate with the Postgres pod? Then what name should I use to "curl" from Tomcat pod?

Comment: you can access the pods using the service name as `curl http:servicename/`

Comment: please edit the question to add details there.

Comment: Again I deployed without ClusterIP service. Now it has only one Service  i.e. NodePort Service  with name "test-service". But when I curl "test-service" from Tomcat pod, it's the same - "Connection Refused"

Comment: I have edited and added the new details below the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229551/discussion-between-krishna-chaurasia-and-dusty).

Comment: Why do your containers run `command: [sleep, infinity]`?  That'd definitely cause a "connection refused" error, since the database and Web server processes aren't actually running.

Comment: (This question would also be much clearer if the names in your YAML were self-consistent, and matched the debug output: the thing named `nginx-statefulset` is neither a StatefulSet nor runs Nginx.  There's also a potential problem since both pods have the same `labels:`, and both Services select both Pods.)

Comment: @DavidMaze, if I don't specify the commands: [sleep, infinity], the pod will CrashLoopBack.

Comment: Database process is already running. I have added the output in question

Comment: And I noticed "curl postgres:5432" sometimes works and sometimes no. Output added in question

Answer (score 1):

You have overridden the default `ENTRYPOINT` in the postgresql image by specifying `deployment.spec.template.containers[0].command`. So now the only process that runs inside the pod of the deployment `nginx-statefulset` is `sleep infinity` and postgres is not running. Removing the command field and adding either `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` or `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust` environment variable should fix the issue. Use the following manifest for `nginx-statefulset`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-statefulset
  namespace: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      BIZID: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        BIZID: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: admin
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: postgredb
```

You have to set the env variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` or `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust`. Without this, the pod will crashloop with the following error message:

```
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
       You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
       superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".

       You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
       connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.

       See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
       https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

Comment: I updated the question. Can you please check again?

Comment: Interesting. I tried using your manifest locally in my kind cluster and noticed that postgres was not running.
Where is your k8s cluster running?
Can you share the command that you executed for the open connections output?

Comment: I'm using GCP compute engines and installed K8 there. I used "netstat -tulpn" command and to check the process running I used "ps aux"

Comment: A service is composed of 2 components: dns entry that maps the query postgres-service to the cluster ip(10.32.0.207 in your case), iptables rules on the k8s node that intercept traffic to the cluster ip and do a dnat to the actual pod ips.
Instead of doing a "curl postgres-service:5432", try doing a curl to the actual postgres pod ip.

Comment: I assume you are running "kubectl exec -it <postgres pod name> -- netstat -tupln". This command executes the "netstat -tupln" in the network namespace of the postgres pod. Surprising that it works since the default postgres image doesn't include the netstat command. Have you added the netstat binary to the image manually?

Comment: I was able to make this work. Installed "ebtables" package and  loaded kernel module - modprobe br_netfilter"

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your yamls, it seems that your tomcat deployment is residing in a namespace called "test", whereas your postgres deployment lives in the "default" namespace.

So, in order to do cross-namespace communication, you will have to append the namespace to the service domain. This one - if executed from the tomcat Pod - should work:

```
curl http://postgres-service.default:5432
```

Alternatively, simply deploy you tomcat to the "default" namespace.

Comment: But they are in the same namespace

Comment: If you are still using the same yamls that you have posted, then tomcat is deployed to the "test" namespace and postgres to the default namespace. If not, then please update the question accordingly.

Comment: yeah I missed the namespace. But when I apply the Yaml file I explicitly use the --namespace command. "kubectl create -f data.yml -n test"

Comment: So all are in the same namespace. I will edit the question

Comment: FYI: If I try to overwrite a namespace defined in a yaml with kubectl, I get an"namespace does not match" error message. This is with kubectl 1.20.

Comment: Do you get the same issue?